# Merge array and implode last element of a array by comma in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge, implode

I have following array, want to merge it and implode last element by comma. First two elements will always be the same,only the last elements will vary, want to implode it by comma.

Input Array

```
[dob] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [dob] => 20 Feb 1989
                [age] => 28
                [data] => abc
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [dob] => 20 Feb, 1989
                [age] => 28
                [data] => xyz
            )

    )
```

Expected output:

Want to get the following output:-

```
[dob]  => Array
        (
            [dob] => 20 Feb 1989
            [age] => 28
            [data] => abc,xyz
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$final_array = [];

$final_array['dob'] = [$array['dob'][0]['dob'],$array['dob'][0]['age'],implode(',',array_column($array['dob'],'data'))];

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/887194

***OR if you don't want to create a new array then do like below:-***

https://eval.in/887204

Comment: with the help of foreach can i generate??

Comment: @YabesNadar  why you need foreach? Any specific reason?

Comment: As far your case `foreach()` is not useful. As you said that first two values of each sub-array will same. So `array_column()` with `implode()` is much better approach rather than `foreach()` in this case.